# Assigning hotkey to set keyframes without using the menu

Tags: animation, keyframes

How could I change the <kbd>i</kbd> hotkey so that it simply sets a keyframe on LocRotScale? If I set key mappings to "industry compatible" this behaviour is mapped to <kbd>S</kbd> but I can't figure out how to make that work within the default key mappings.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately even though that allows you to remove the keyframe menu from the hotkey i can't replicate the fuctionality that S does in industry compatible mode, the command is idental but behaves differently.

Comment: not clear to me, what is "industry compatible"?

Comment: Under "Keymap" you can change it from "Blender" to "Industry Compatible" which makes all the hotkeys similar to Maya. In Maya S sets a keyframe on all keyable attributes for the selected object and this appears to be the same when you switch to industry compatible key mapping. I want to keep Blender's default keymappings apart from this one thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

Go to "Preferences -> Keymap" and search for "insert keyframe".

Choose which view you want to edit the hotkey for. For example, under "Pose" click the triangle and it'll show you the python command "anim.keyframe_insert_menu"

[image]

Simply change it to "anim.keyframe_insert" and press Enter.

There's one more thing to do. If you go into Pose Mode now, select a bone and press <kbd>i</kbd> - you won't get the menu anymore BUT you'll get an error "No active keying set".

Under the python code is a confusingly greyed out drop-down menu. Click that and choose what you want the <kbd>i</kbd> shortcut to do, in my case I chose "Whole Character"

[image]

That's it! Now when in Pose Mode selecting one controller and pressing <kbd>i</kbd> now instantly keys everything on the rig!

Comment: you cant add a keyframe for a solid object. error message "cant found keyset"